# Getting null when trying to extract year value from a date

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My code is the following:

```
NSString *dateString = @"1339007317";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSString *year = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",year);//null
```

How to fix that? thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using **unix timestamp** and you can convert **unix timestamp** into year or any date format as :

```
//Posted Date Format
NSString *dateStr = @"1339007317";
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[dateStr doubleValue]];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy"]; //Here you can set any date format Ex:@"dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm a" or@"dd/MM/yyyyy" according to your requirement
[dateFormatter1 setLocale:locale];
[dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

dateStr = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate: date];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: There is no need to set the timezone. It will default to the current timezone. Also, why set the locale to `en-US` (besides - it should be `en_US`)?

Answer (score 0):

You need two date formats. The first should match the format of the string you wish to convert to an `NSDate`. The second format needs to represent the format you want. Use the 2nd to convert the `NSDate` to the new string.

Also, why do you create a date object then immediately replace it with a new one?

Change this:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

to:

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Your code needs to be like this:

```
NSString *dateString = @"1339007317";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"???"]; // format that matches the dateString
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"]; // the desired new format
NSString *year = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",year);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanx, but I already tried to automatically assign value ot date without allocating and doesn't work, how about your first suggestion, can you elaborate ?

Comment: What date format is your string "1339007317"? It's not just year.